# amount of data that can be hold in shared memory CUDA

Tags: cuda

In my gpu max threads per block is 1024. I am working on a image processing project using CUDA. Now if I want to use shared memory is that mean that I can only work with 1024 pixels using one block and need to copy only those 1024 elements to the shared memory

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear, so I will answer to what is asked in the title.

The amount of data that can be hold in shared memory in CUDA depends on the Compute Capability of your GPU.
For instance, on CC 2.x and 3.x :

> On devices of compute capability 2.x and 3.x, each multiprocessor has 64KB of on-chip memory that can be partitioned between L1 cache and shared memory.

See ***Configuring the amount of shared memory*** section here : [Nvidia Parallel Forall Devblog : Using Shared Memory in CUDA C/C++](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/)

The optimization you have to think about is to avoid bank conflicts by mapping the threads' access to memory banks. This is introduced in this blog and you should read about it.